# Trying to suppress clang false positive leak warning

Tags: c, suppress-warnings, clang-static-analyzer, false-positive

I am using clang static analysis under Xcode 6.4 (6E35b), and getting a false positive warning about a potential memory leak.  I do explicitly free the memory in question, but the freeing happens in a different compilation unit.  Here is my MWE:

file2.c: Performs the actual freeing.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
void my_free(const void* p) {
    free((void*) p);
}
```

file1.c: Allocates memory and explicitly frees it through an external function.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
void my_free(const void* p);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    void* data = malloc(1);
    if(data) my_free(data);
    return 0; /* <-- "Potential leak of memory pointed to by 'data'" */
}
```

When I define `my_free()` in the same compilation unit as its invocation, no warning is generated, but of course I need to invoke `my_free()` from a large number of different source files.

I have read through [FAQ and How to Deal with Common False Positives](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/faq.html), but it does not address my situation.  What can I do to assure clang that I really am freeing the memory in question?

In case the version information is relevant:

```
% clang --version
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
```

Comment: On a side note, I would expect "`my_free`" to come in pair with "`my_malloc`".

Comment: @Groo:  Good point.  This MWE may be a little misleading in what it suggests, but I agree that allocation and deallocation should generally come in pairs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to fix that would be to add code specific for the analyser, in your header file:

```
#ifdef __clang_analyzer__
#define my_free free
#endif
```

This will make the static analyser think you're using the classic `free` function and stop complaining.

Comment: Good to know +1

Comment: A wonderful solution.  In context I have to do things a little differently or the compiler complains when I try to define function `my_free()`, but the principle holds.  Thank you.